# Angular material 6.2.1 "mat-form-field-infix" overwrite width

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to overwrite default width `180px` in `mat-form-field-infix` without custom CSS

```html
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option>{{ option.test}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field fxFlex>
  <input matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

full screen output
[image]

But small screen display horizontal scrollbar

stack

```
"@angular/cdk": "^6.2.1",
"@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.16",
"@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/material": "^6.2.1",
```

Thanks

Comment: Since you are using `flex-layout` you could use `fxFlex.xs="[your_width_here]"`

Comment: @Lalji, Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: @raga no, I have use default width

Comment: @MichaelDoye your solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The closest i've found is to use a style binding for the form field:

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" [style.width.px]="200">
```

otherwise it's using the old approach of custom css.... like so:

add the attribute `class="datepicker"` to your `<mat-form-field>` and in your css do

```
.datepicker {width:200px;}
```

I'm having a similar problem with one of my form fields being larger than the rest and that's what I did to solve it. See the date picker form field here [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3hxsdt):

Comment: Using `[style.width.px]` on `mat-form-field` is a nice solution.

Answer (score 4):

In my solution I am using an ElementRef to override the width of the mat-form-field-infix:

```
   <mat-form-field
       #field
   </mat-form-field>
```

Then in the component:

```
@ViewChild('field', { read: ElementRef }) field: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
    var el = this.field.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-form-field-infix');
    el.style.width = 'auto';
}
```

I think altough this does not meet your requirment 'without custom css'. But maybe this can be helpfull for you.